# Radio-button moves when resizing window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The radio-buttons on my interface move when resizing the interface. I want to know how to prevent that. I thought that setting horizontal and vertical alignments were enough but it didn't work. Any ideas?
[image: Before resize][image: after resize]

Here is the code to my grid:

```
  <Grid  Margin="20,3,10,-10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="105"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="255"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="23"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="98"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="240"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="114"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="273*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!--ROW 0-->
                        <!--COLUMN 0 & 1-->
                        <TextBlock Text="Customer" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,7" Height="16" Width="54"/>
                        <dxe:ButtonEdit Name="xbteCustomer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" AllowDefaultButton="False" NullTextForeground="Black" LostFocus="xcbeControl_LostFocus"
                                        KeyDown="xcbeControl_KeyDown" Margin="6,5,21,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#D6D6D6" 
                                        NullText="Select" EditValueChanged="xcbeEvent_EditValueChanged" TabIndex="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <dxe:ButtonEdit.Buttons>
                                <dxe:ButtonInfo x:Name="xbteSearchCustomer" Content="Search" GlyphKind="Search" Click="xbteFilter_Click"/>
                            </dxe:ButtonEdit.Buttons>
                        </dxe:ButtonEdit>
                        <!--<dxg:LookUpEdit x:Name="xcbeCustomerId" Grid.Row="0"  FilterCondition="Contains"  Grid.Column="1" EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                DisplayMember="CustomerName" ValueMember="CustomerId" Margin="5,5,0,0" Width="250" PopupOpening="xcbeCustomerId_PopupOpening">
                            <dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="PART_GridControl" Loaded="PART_GridControl_Loaded">
                                        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcCustomerId" FieldName="CustomerId" Visible="False"/>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcCustomerCode" FieldName="CustomerCode" Header="Code" Width="100"/>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcCustomerName" FieldName="CustomerName" Header="Name"/>
                                        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                        <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                            <dxg:TableView AutoWidth="True" AllowBestFit="True"/>
                                        </dxg:GridControl.View>
                                    </dxg:GridControl>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
                        </dxg:LookUpEdit>-->
                        <!--COLUMN 3 & 4-->
                        <TextBlock Text="Account Code" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="3,7,0,7" Height="16" Width="79"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="xtxtAccountCode" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="150" Margin="0,5,0,0" MaxLength="10" />

                        <!--ROW 1-->
                        <!--COLUMN 0 & 1-->
                        <TextBlock Text="Account Name" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,7" Height="16" Width="83"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="xtxtAccountName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging" Margin="6,5,21,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                        <!--COLUMN 3 & 4-->
                        <TextBlock Text="Credit Limit" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="3,7,0,7" Height="16" Width="66"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="xtxtCreditLimit" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Width="150" DisplayFormatString="c" MaskType="RegEx" Mask="(\d+(.\d){0,0})+" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="Default OU" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,7,0,7" Height="16" Width="63"/>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="xcbeDefaultOUId" DisplayMember="Value" ValueMember="Key" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" NullTextForeground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" NullText="Select" Width="150"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,0"  
                                          EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging"/>

                        <!--ROW 2-->
                        <!--COLUMN 0 & 1-->
                        <TextBlock Text="Sales Team" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,7" Height="16" Width="62"/>
                        <dxg:LookUpEdit x:Name="xcbeSalesTeamId"  FilterCondition="Contains" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                DisplayMember="TeamName" ValueMember="SalesTeamId" Width="150" Margin="6,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25">
                            <dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="PART_GridControl" Loaded="PART_GridControl_Loaded">
                                        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcSalesTeamId" FieldName="SalesTeamId" Visible="False"/>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcTeamCode" FieldName="TeamCode" Header="Code" Width="100"/>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcTeamName" FieldName="TeamName" Header="Name"/>
                                        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                        <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                            <dxg:TableView AutoWidth="True" AllowBestFit="True"/>
                                        </dxg:GridControl.View>
                                    </dxg:GridControl>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
                        </dxg:LookUpEdit>

                        <!--COLUMN 3 & 4-->
                        <TextBlock Text="UOM" Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="3" FontWeight="Bold" Height="16" Margin="3,7,0,7" Width="86"/>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="xcbeUOM"  Grid.Row="3"    Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" NullText="Select" NullTextForeground="Black"
                                         Margin="0,5,0,0" DisplayMember="Value" ValueMember="Key"  
                            EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging" EditValueChanged="xcbeUOM_EditValueChanged"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="UOM Conversion" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" FontWeight="Bold" Height="16" Margin="3,7,0,7" Width="95" />
                        <dxg:LookUpEdit x:Name="xlueUOMConversion" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging"
                                        DisplayMember="Conversiontxt"  AutoPopulateColumns="False" ValueMember="UOMConversionId" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="25" NullText="Select" NullTextForeground="Black">
                            <dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="PART_GridControl">
                                        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcConversionID" FieldName="UOMconversionId" Header="Id"  Visible="False"/>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcConversiontxt" FieldName="Conversiontxt" Header="Conversion" Width="120"/>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcConversion" FieldName="Conversion" Header="Conversion Rate" Width="70"/>
                                        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                        <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                            <dxg:TableView AutoWidth="True" />
                                        </dxg:GridControl.View>
                                    </dxg:GridControl>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
                        </dxg:LookUpEdit>



                        <TextBlock Text="Split Freight"     Grid.Row="0"    Grid.Column="7" FontWeight="Bold" Height="16" Margin="0,7" Width="70" />
                        <RadioButton Name="xrbtSplitFreight" Content="" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="9" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="xrbtButton_Checked" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="18"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="Print Comment"     Grid.Row="1"    Grid.Column="7" FontWeight="Bold" Height="16" Margin="0,7" Width="114" />
                        <RadioButton Name="xrbtPrintComment"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="9" Checked="xrbtButton_Checked" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="18" />

                        <TextBlock Text="Do Not Split Freight"      Grid.Row="2"    Grid.Column="7" FontWeight="Bold" Height="16" Margin="0,7" Width="114" />
                        <RadioButton Name="xrbtDonotSplitFreight"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Checked="xrbtButton_Checked" FontWeight="Bold" Width="18"/>

                        <!--ROW 3-->
                        <!--COLUMN 0 & 1-->
                        <TextBlock Text="Sales Rep" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,7" Height="16" Width="53"/>
                        <dxg:LookUpEdit x:Name="xcbeSalesRepId"  FilterCondition="Contains" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                DisplayMember="FullName" ValueMember="SalesRepId" Width="150" Margin="6,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="PART_GridControl" Loaded="PART_GridControl_Loaded" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcSalesRepId" FieldName="SalesRepId" Visible="False"/>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcCode" FieldName="Code" Header="Code" Width="100" />
                                            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcPerson" FieldName="FullName" Header="Full Name" Width="Auto" />
                                        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                        <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                            <dxg:TableView AllowBestFit="True"/>
                                        </dxg:GridControl.View>
                                    </dxg:GridControl>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
                        </dxg:LookUpEdit>

                        <!--ROW 4-->
                        <!--COLUMN 0 & 1-->
                        <TextBlock Text="Status" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,7" Height="16" Width="35"/>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="xcbeCustomerStatusId" Grid.Row="4" DisplayMember="Value" ValueMember="Key" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="6,5,0,0" 
                EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging"/>

                        <!--ROW 5-->
                        <!--COLUMN 0 & 1-->
                        <TextBlock Text="Payment Term" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,7" Height="16" Width="81"/>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="xcbeCustomerTermId" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" DisplayMember="Value" ValueMember="Key" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="6,5,0,0"  
                EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging"/>
                        <!--row 6-->

                        <TextBlock Text="Comment"           Grid.Row="6"    Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="16" Width="55"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="xtxtNote"     Grid.Row="6"    Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" EditValueChanging="Event_EditValueChanging" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="6,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <!--radio button-->
                        <!--<dxe:ListBoxEdit Name="xrbSplitFreight" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="7" FontWeight="Bold"  Grid.Column="8" Height="90" VerticalAlignment="center"  Width="174" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ShowBorder="False">
                            <dxe:ListBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                                <dxe:RadioListBoxEditStyleSettings />
                            </dxe:ListBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                        </dxe:ListBoxEdit>-->
                    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of your grid? I bet it's autosize or something - nothing to do with your button itself.

Comment: just edited the post

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of moved radio button?

Comment: just added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because you define you last (9th column with index 8) as
`"20*"/`.

This will make your 9th column grow same as 10th column (`"273*"`) - 
when it grows your `RadioButtons` move to the right, because they are in the 10th column, which gets pushed from 9th column growing :)

Comment: You're welcome ;) Layout Manager can be horrifying  ;)